# How do I create a local server instance from a vhd downloaded from Azure?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, virtualization

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I need to create a local server instance from a vhd downloaded from azure. So far I have downloaded the disk image and created a local vm. I can log in normally, but the main problem is that the internet is not working, and it should get an address from dhcp. I assume it's the drivers.

What is the procedure to get this working? I would like to avoid any work on the production server like generalization because I don't have enough knowledge if something goes wrong and the software running on that server is important for me. On local VM I can do whatever it takes to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with various drivers and finally the
command

`sudo dhclient eth0`

did the job. After that I've managed to generate new netplan config and enter my static ip.